# Run Custom Shell Script [cp] Embed Pods Framework

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

My Project was building fine before the latest update of xcode.Currently running 10.1 version of xcode and high sierra below are the errors screenshot

[image]

Comment: First of all, have you tried cleaning the build folder using shift-command-k?

Comment: Yes i did but didn't worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is wrong without script. By error description `bad interpreter: Operation not permitted` I can have a guess you have syntax error in script or one of commands in script requires `sudo`.